# Django-templates: Concatenate string variables with strings in with block

Tags: django, django-templates

So I'm looking to do something like this to keep things DRY:

```
{% with share_text=author.name + "released" + book.title + "via:myapp" %}
    do stuff with {{share_text}}
{% endwith %}
```

However, I'm getting Django template errors like "could not parse remainder" and "with received invalid operator `+`".

Comment: The idea is *not* to do this in a template (Django templates deliberately are *less* expressive than Python code, to avoid writing business logic in the template), but in a view, or use `{{author.name}}released{{book.title}}`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem while I wholefully agree with the whole idea of avoiding _business_ code in templates, it doesn't apply here - this is obviously presentation - and sometime you have to reuse the same formatted string in different places in a template and don't want to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django template language is NOT python (ever if it sometimes looks a bit similar), so don't expect python code to work here. Use template filters / tags. In your case [the builtin `add` templatefilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) should work:

```
{% with share_text=author.name|add:"released"|add:book.title|add:"via:myapp" %}
```

but please carefully read the limitations and gotchas mentioned in the doc. Else you can write your own custom filter or templatetag, that's really easy.